# TCPDF imprimir resultados de una consulta MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Hola pues tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de seleccionar todos los registros de una tabla y después pasarlos a un archivo pdf, el problema es que solo imprime un registro en el pdf, cuando en realidad deben ser 3 que son los que tengo en la bd, les dejo el codigo para que me vean con mejor detalle.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS");

foreach($sql as $key => $value) {

$html='

<h1 align="center">Usuarios</h1><br>
<table style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 10px; border: 1px solid #666;" align="center">

    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Nombres</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Apellidos</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Correo</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Usuario</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Privilegio</td>

    </tr>




        <tr>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["nombres"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["apellidos"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["correo"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["usuario"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["privilegio"].'</td>

    </tr>
    </table>';
     } //Cierra foreach
     $pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, false, false, ''); //Salida PDF
     $pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
```

Resultado en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Pon solo dentro del for el tr con los nuevos valores porque de la forma que lo estas haciendo estas sobreescribiendo toda la tabla y al final muestras una sola tabla con un solo valor sería algo como:

```
html = '
<h1 align="center">Usuarios</h1><br>
<table style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 10px; border: 1px solid #666;" align="center">    
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Nombres</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Apellidos</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Correo</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Usuario</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Privilegio</td>    
    </tr>';
foreach($sql as $key => $value) {
 html .=' <tr>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["nombres"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["apellidos"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["correo"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["usuario"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["privilegio"].'</td>

    </tr>';
}
$html.='</table>'
$pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, false, false, ''); //Salida PDF
$pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Añadí el código, no imprime nada en el pdf ni la etiqueta <h1>

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta en lo que tienes dentro de tu loop.  Solo debes de poner lo que quieres que se repita.  Quedaria asi:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS");  

$html='

<h1 align="center">Usuarios</h1><br>
<table style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 10px; border: 1px solid #666;" align="center">

    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Nombres</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Apellidos</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Correo</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Usuario</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666;">Privilegio</td>

    </tr>';    

    foreach($sql as $key => $value) {

    $html .= '<tr>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["nombres"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["apellidos"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["correo"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["usuario"].'</td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">'.$value["privilegio"].'</td>

    </tr>';
    } //Cierra foreach
    $html .= '</table>';

     $pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, false, false, ''); //Salida PDF
     $pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Agregue el código, pero no imprime nada ni el <h1>usuarios esta en blanco